# Inequality for two absolute value variables. How to graph them and also solve them.

Tags: inequality

[image]

I tried to solve for y and didnt know how to solve for 2 variables. My book has an example of only one absolute value and in this case there are 2. would love to learn how to plot these aswell if someone has the idea to do that.

Comment: Is that a $1$ or an L? Please rewrite it as a TexCode. For example: $|x-1| + |y| \le 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $z>0\to|z|=z$ and $z<0\to|z|=-z$ (the absolute value is a piecewise linear function), and decompose the domain.

$$x-1>0\land y>0\to x-1+y\le 2$$
$$x-1<0\land y>0\to 1-x+y\le 2$$
$$x-1>0\land y<0\to x-1-y\le 2$$
$$x-1<0\land y<0\to 1-x-y\le 2$$

Every set of inequations defines a region with three sides, possibly empty or unbounded.

In this particular case, you will find a diamond shape made of four triangles.

Comment: how do i know the graph solution? @Yves Daoust .

Comment: You take a sheet of paper, a pencil, a ruler and you hatch the half planes.

Comment: sorry didnt see you edited the last line in the previous post! :) thnaks a ton.

Comment: "take a sheet of paper, a pencil, a ruler and you hatch the half planes": do it, you'll learn from that.